# How to obtain the magnetic field of the following set up

Tags: differential-equations, physics, vector-calculus

This is the experimental set up: A ferromagnetic cylindrical disk (of irrelevant dimensions) has either sides set at different electric potentials (left side at 0 volts and right side at 1 volt). A radio frequency current is passed through the disk and flows between these two regions. I have been able to use *mathematica* to determine the electric field the disk exhibits but am unsure of how to obtain the corresponding magnetic field. For the sake of the problem let the current be 1 mA with frequency 1 Ghz. Let the disk have diameter 10 microns and height 0.5 microns.

```
R1 = 
  ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 <= 1 ∧ Abs[z] <= 0.1, 
    {{x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -0.1, 0.1}}]

DBC1 = {
  DirichletCondition[u[x, y, z] == 0, 
    (x^2 + y^2 <= 1 ∧ -1 <= x <= -0.8 ∧ Abs[y] <= 0.6 ∧ Abs[z] == 0.1)], 
  DirichletCondition[u[x, y, z] == 1, 
    (x^2 + y^2 <= 1 ∧ 0.8 <= x <= 1 ∧ Abs[y] <= 0.6 ∧ Abs[z] == 0.1)]
}

pot = 
  NDSolveValue[{Laplacian[u[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] == 0, DBC1}, 
    u, Element[{x, y, z}, R1]]

Efield = -Grad[pot[x, y, z], {x, y, z}]
```

Any tips on how I would go about obtaining the magnetic field from the information I have would be a great help.

Comment: To get the magnetic field, you need the  current **density** as a function of position, not just the current. This isn't a *Mathematica* problem, though.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue it raises is not a  _Mathematica_ issue but a physics issue. That it is formulated in terms of _Mathematica_ is not sufficient to make it an appropriate question for _Mathematica_.SE.

Comment: Yes, I think that is a good idea.